# Get Woocommerce product tag post count via a shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I need to count the number of times a "product tag" is used across the website. Each product has a number of tags associated with it.

I thought about creating a shortcode which I can then reference when needed. The shortcode I have created below crashes the website.

```
// function 
function tag_count_shortcode() { 
 
// Identify the tag ID and then run a count. 
$term = get_tag( $tag_ID );
$count = $term->count; 
 
// Output the total number of times a tag is used
return $count;
} 
// register shortcode
add_shortcode('tagcount', 'tag_count_shortcode');
```

Im not sure where I am going wrong with this. Would really appreciate any assistance.

*Platform: WordPress |
File with code: "Functions.php"*

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about product tags which is a WooCommerce custom taxonomy and not WordPress Tags.

Also a product can have many product tags, so the following code will handle the count on the first product tag term. This shortcode also handle some arguments:

- the `taxonomy` (can handle any custom taxonomy, WordPress tag and category too) - By default: product tag
- the `term_id` (can handle any defined term ID) - by default it gets the term on single product pages
- the `post_id` - By default the current product ID

The code:

```
function term_count_shortcode( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'product_tag', // Product tag taxonomy (by default)
        'term_id' => 0,
        'post_id' => get_queried_object_id(), // The current post ID
    ), $atts ) );

    // For a defined term ID
    if( $term_id > 0 ) {
        // Get the WP_term object
        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $term_id, $taxonomy );

        if( is_a( $term, 'WP_Term' ) )
            $count = $term->count;
        else
            $count = 0;
    }
    // On product single pages
    elseif ( is_product() && $term_id == 0 && $post_id > 0 ) {
        // Get the product tag post terms
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy );
        // Get the first term in the array
        $term  = is_array($terms) ? reset( $terms ) : '';

        if( is_a( $term, 'WP_Term' ) )
            $count = $term->count;
        else
            $count = 0;
    } else {
        $count = false;
    }
    return $count;
}
add_shortcode('term_count', 'term_count_shortcode');
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**USAGE:**

1). **Basic usage:** Display the first product tag count from product single page: `[term_count]`

2). **Usage with arguments:**

- With a defined term ID: `[term_count term_id="58"]`
- With a defined term ID and Taxonomy: `[term_count term_id="15" taxonomy="product_cat"]`
- With a defined term ID and post ID: `[term_count term_id="15" post_id="37"]`

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much for such a detailed answer. I really appreciate you assistance on this! The code works flawlessly! Thank you so much!